# Barcode in java

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, barcode

I have a question, I am creating a bar code and print it in a pdf file, and what you get is the code and below the series of numbers that correspond to that code, I want to know how to disappear Series of numbers, I just want to display the bar code, nothing else ..... if anyone knows how to do it, we really appreciate it, I've looking for solutions on google, but have not found anything that I solved my problem. Thank you very much.

I'm using the iText library: com.lowagie.text.pdf.Barcode39.

This is my code:

```
Barcode39 code = new Barcode39();

code.setCode("12011040803");

PdfContentByte pdfPageCodeBar = pdfStamper.getOverContent(1);
com.lowagie.text.Image imgBarCode = code.createImageWithBarcode(pdfPageCodeBar, Color.BLACK, Color.black);

imgBarCode.setAbsolutePosition(310, 196);

imgBarCode.scaleAbsolute(184, 27);

pdfPageCodeBar.addImage(imgBarCode);
```

Comment: Might help to know what you are using. Assuming [this](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/PDF/pdf-itext/com/lowagie/text/pdf/Barcode39.java.java-doc.htm).

Comment: sorry!!!  I'm using the iText library: com.lowagie.text.pdf.Barcode39

Comment: [Barcode4J](http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/index.html) is a very good alternative if you're ever in need of an alternative to the lowagie/iText library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
setFont(null);
```

which suppresses text generation.

Comment: Please mark it as the correct answer so future users can find it easily.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the Bar, without the number. The API specify this :

```
java.awt.Image createAwtImage(Color foreground, Color background)(Code)
```

=> Creates a java.awt.Image. This image only contains the bars without any text.

next time tell us what tools you are using :).

[source](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/PDF/pdf-itext/com/lowagie/text/pdf/Barcode39.java.java-doc.htm#createAwtImageColorColor)

Comment: thanks for your idea, but you have one more???.... I tried your option, but didn't work =(

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Barcode39 code = new Barcode39();

code.setCode("12011040803");
code.setStartStopText(false);
```

then generate your image.